# Amazon Polly, What Voices are for What Language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I have been searching the internet for a list as to what Polly voices go with what language. Does anyone know which ones go together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DescribeVoices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_DescribeVoices.html) API call to obtain information about each voice.

```
$ aws polly describe-voices --region us-east-1
{
    "Voices": [
        {
            "Gender": "Female", 
            "Name": "Joanna", 
            "LanguageName": "US English", 
            "Id": "Joanna", 
            "LanguageCode": "en-US"
        }, 
        {
            "Gender": "Female", 
            "Name": "Mizuki", 
            "LanguageName": "Japanese", 
            "Id": "Mizuki", 
            "LanguageCode": "ja-JP"
        }, 
        {
            "Gender": "Female", 
            "Name": "Filiz", 
            "LanguageName": "Turkish", 
            "Id": "Filiz", 
            "LanguageCode": "tr-TR"
        }, 
        etc.
```

The `LanguageCode` is in [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) format, which includes the **language** and **country**.